# What is the simplest parsing algorithm that can parse C code?

Tags: c, parsing

Does anyone know what the weakest family of widely-used parsing algorithms is that can parse C code?  That is, is the C grammar LL(1), LR(0), LALR(1), etc.?  I'm curious because as a side project I'm interested in writing a parser generator for one of these families and would like to ultimately be able to parse C code for another side project.

Comment: Most parsers are built in way that recognizes "too much", and the overage is rejected by additional checks outside the parser.  That being the case, the regex  "[.]*"  is the weakest parser that will parse C, albeit with a lot of additional semantic checks.  Once this is obvious, it should be clear you can make any parser generator process C, modulo extra hacking.   (It seems completely crazy to write a parser that accepts too little as its starting place).

Comment: I just tripped over this question again.  The obvious practical answer is, "hand-coded top down recursive".  I'd bet my bottom dollar that's how the first C parser was built (long before YACC :)  The interesting question on top of this is, how much hackiness does it take beyond the basics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [Bison uses an LALR(1)](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/gnu/gcc/bison_15.html#GLOSS21) parser.  LALR parsers are more robust than LL parsers, but are also more complex.  From this I suspect that LALR(1) is probably the weakest parsing algorithm which can parse C code.

Unless you're really set on rolling your own recognizer. [ANTLR](HTTP://WWW.ANTLR.ORG) would probably be your best bet to do this.  ANTLR uses an LL* algorithm (which is, effectively, LALR).