# C++ file parser and function extractor

Tags: c++, qt, text-parsing

I need to develop a Qt/C++ software that reads in C++ source files, finds the dependencies, and copies only the code used from the dependent files into a file of the same name.

As an example. main.cpp calls foo(). foo() is declared in foofuncs.h and defined in foofuncs.cpp. foofuncs has many different functions other than foo(). I need to copy the foo() declaration from foofuncs.h to a new file (e.g. foofuncs.h.copy) which would just have the foo() declaration (and relevant includes). Similarly I would do the same to foofuncs.cpp.copy which would just contain the foo() definition (as well as the #include "foo.h", etc). This will likely need some kind of recursive process to go through all the includes, etc.

So my question is how can I do that? Can I use QRegularExpressions to find the code blocks? If so I need help with that. Also, is there any related open-source tools to be integrated in my Qt app to help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Understanding/parsing C-code with regular expressions is very hard, if you cannot make a LOT of assumptions on coding style - I tried. Sounds like you will be getting quite close to writing a compiler.

Comment: @Yunnosch about the regExps I think it must be so hard. I think using some tools like Doxygen might help

Comment: Parsing C++ code with C++ without a library designed to do it is a very tough problem.  But this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166177).  What are you really trying to do that requires moving C++ code between files? I suspect you are trying to implement some sort of optimizer that eliminates dead code... there are tools for that.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: @Yunnosch I mean I'm agree you that parsing c-code with regular expressions is very hard!

Comment: I think "What is the simplest way to parse complex C code?" should be duplicate, just because I have seen this kind of question more than once. If nobody finds a dupe, I propose trying to turn this into the future dupe target for this kind of quesiton. I.e. do not close and delete too quickly, search for dupes first (Yes, I did close-vote, I kind of changed my mind...) Please only close-vote as dupe...

Comment: This for example I consider NOT a dupe, because OP is aware that he is asking about parsing C code (C or C++; it is the same problem, just harder for C++ I believe). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787983/what-is-the-simplest-parsing-algorithm-that-can-parse-c-code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot parse C++ code using regular expressions.

Some directions:

- use clang, to parse the code, then using clang's API create code
- search for `compiler-compiler`.
- I found this C++ parser library to use instead of clang, you can look into it: https://github.com/foonathan/cppast
- You can also look into https://www.antlr.org/

Don't even try to parse C++ code yourself, it's a never ending story.